# No change in the filling colored knob jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I plugged in the form of a knob jquery in this way:

```
<input id="Totali" type="text" class="dial" value="30" data-angleOffset="-125" data-angleArc="250" data-fgColor="#00a0e0" data-angleOffset=-125 data-width="70" data-displayInput="true" data-readOnly="true" data-thickness=".15" />
<input id="Fermi" type="text" class="dial" value="30" data-angleOffset="-125" data-angleArc="250" data-fgColor="#00a0e0" data-angleOffset=-125 data-width="70" data-displayInput="true" data-readOnly="true" data-thickness=".15" />
```

and at the time of the change in the code:

```
$('.dial')
    .trigger(
        'configure', {
            "min": 0,
            "max": parseInt(markers.length)
        }
);

$('.dial[id=Totali]')
    .val(parseInt(markers.length))
    .trigger('change');

$('.dial[id=Fermi]')
    .val(parseInt(21))
    .trigger('change');
```

But it only changes the label but not the fill color:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
$('.dial[id=Totali]')
$('.dial[id=Fermi]')
```

to

```
$('#Totali')
$('#Fermi')
```